# How to remove the average from vmstat?

Tags: linux, vmstat

In the `man vmstat` there is the following explanation about the first line:

> The first report produced gives averages since the last reboot. 
>   Additional reports give information on a sampling period of length
>   delay.  The process and memory reports are instantaneous in either
>   case

I wanna know how can I ignore the first line

```
procs -----------memory---------- ---swap-- -----io---- --system-- -----cpu------
 r  b   swpd   free   buff  cache   si   so    bi    bo   in   cs us sy id wa st
 1  0      0    149     20   4393    0    0   572  3723    0    0 18  1 74  7  0 <I want to remove this line
 1  0      0    149     20   4393    0    0     0     0 1043  280 50  0 50  0  0
 1  0      0    149     20   4393    0    0     0    60 1041  268 50  0 50  0  0
 1  0      0    149     20   4393    0    0     0     0 1042  250 50  0 50  0  0
 1  0      0    149     20   4393    0    0     0     8 1025  242 50  0 50  0  0
 1  0      0    149     20   4393    0    0     0     0 1025  250 50  0 50  0  0
 1  0      0    149     20   4393    0    0     0    16 1025  249 50  0 50  0  0
```

How can I do this?

Comment: `vmstat | awk 'NR>1'`

Comment: @Jetchisel, that removes the first header line, not the first data line.

Comment: All lines are averages. The first one just has a longer time-span, and shows all the graft done to get the system running.

Comment: The OP, says, `wanna know how can I ignore the first line` No having any knowledge of what vm stat is...

Comment: It seems you want to ignore the *third* line. `awk 'NR != 3'`?

Comment: @Jetchisel If you scroll right on the sample output, there is annotation. Agreed the documentation is hazy. I think it implies the memory values are polled once at the end of the delay interval, and the cpu stats are cumulative since boot time, with the change in the delay interval averaged per second. The issue is that the first "interval" has no base data, so it uses all zeros (equivalent to boot time).

Comment: @Kamil I try never to trust the stability of heading texts, across systems or under different options. Some codes even act differently to a terminal or a pipe or file. Even ls and ls | cat are different.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

awk to remove the first line starting with a numeric field.

```
vmstat | awk '!( $1 ~ /^[0-9]+$/ && x++ == 0)'
```